# How do I modify all of a selected class' child divs, in HTML?

Tags: javascript, css

- I have a class in which there are large no. of div's.
- I want to access those id's inside a class and apply the animation play state property

Here is my code:

```
<div class="p5pg5QXlX-an-stage">
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-1">
                    <div><img height="416" width="320" src="assets/overlay1.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-2">
                    <div><img height="416" width="320" src="assets/float.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-3">
                    <div><img height="416" width="320" src="assets/temple.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-4">
                    <div><img height="416" width="320" src="assets/go.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-5">
                    <div><img height="416" width="320" src="assets/da.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-6">
                    <div><img height="416" width="320" src="assets/va.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-7">
                    <div><img height="416" width="320" src="assets/ri.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-8">
                    <div><img height="416" width="320" src="assets/matha.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-9">
                    <div><img height="416" width="320" src="assets/pu.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-10">
                    <div><img height="416" width="320" src="assets/shka.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-11">
                    <div><img height="416" width="320" src="assets/raa.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-12">
                    <div><img height="416" width="320" src="assets/luu.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-13">
                    <div><img height="480" width="320" src="assets/page1hw.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-14">
                    <div><img height="416" width="320" src="assets/panel.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-15"></div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-16">
                    <div><img height="89" width="89" src="assets/rplay.png">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-17">
                <img height="49" width="49" src="assets/555b175b463b9mFtlk8d8BP4hFbiCHF1w.png">
                <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**I want to apply animation state property to all the id's so please tell me how to access the id's inside a class?**

I have done this :

```
var id=document.getElementByClassName("p5pg5QXlX-an-stage");
id.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState="paused";
```

but it didn't work,i have seen in the inspect element the var id gives a bunch of id's so how i can access all the id's & i don't want to hard-code the each id by name like:

```
document.getElementById("p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-2").WebkitAnimationPlayState="paused";
```

because i want a generic code of this so please help me in this & try to give the sol'n in javascript.

Comment: you have to add a class to all the items to be able to list them and get their id. In your actual code your items are not "in a class". They are just inside a div with a specific class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".p5pg5QXlX-an-stage > div");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){
     el.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState="paused";
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I understand you are trying to do something to all the child divs inside the class.

Use your original selection and iterate over all the child divs that you want to apply state to, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672647/how-can-i-iterate-through-an-elements-child-nodes-using-javascript).

So:

```
var children = document.getElementsByClassName("p5pg5QXlX-an-stage")[0].childNodes;
children.forEach(function(node){
  node.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState="paused";
})
```

Comment: it is giving error by saying childNodes not defined

Comment: Sorry about that, I referenced `childNodes` in line 2 instead of the newly declared `children` array. The snippet is now updated. That said, I highly recommend not pasting code to solve your problem. Try to understand what is happening on each line and you will learn more!

Comment: now it's saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: Try examining the selector: what you were assigning `id` to in your question. We're trying to get the child nodes of that selection. What do you find when you console log `id`?

Comment: why it is not storing the child nodes of that class?

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't think document has a getElementByClassName (singular) method, just getElementsByClassName.  When you run your code as it is written in your question, does it throw any errors? I've updated the answer. Give that a shot?

Comment: no at that time there was no error, i have written like this,now it saying: children.forEach is not afunction

Comment: now it is storing the child, how i will apply forEach in all the childes?

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-2")` is a correct statement if you are going to access a single unique HTML element. You can replace "`p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-2"` with Javascript `var` to make the selection dynamic, like:

```
var id;
document.getElementById(id)
```

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the id's directly using css or JavaScript. No two elements should have the same id. `document.getElementById(id_string)` is for JavaScript and `#myID` is for CSS

Answer (score 0):

as I understand so far, you are trying to do something with div child
I would suggest to use wildcard to select all div child:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-"]');
for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++){
    console.log(elems[i]);
}
```